# Windows Mobile 6 - Is it possible to programmatically access the word completion dictionary

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework

I would like to be able to programmatically control the word completion list for a particular textbox in my windows mobile application.  Does anyone know if this is possible and if so how would this be done?

Answer (score 1):

You can turn these elements on and off with a p/invoke call.  See below:

```
public static class InputContext
{
    private enum SHIC_FEATURE : uint
    {
        RESTOREDEFAULT = 0,
        AUTOCORRECT = 1,
        AUTOSUGGEST = 2,
        HAVETRAILER = 3,
        CLASS = 4
    }

    [DllImport("aygshell.dll")]
    private static extern int SHSetInputContext(IntPtr hwnd, SHIC_FEATURE dwFeature, ref bool lpValue);

    public static void SetAutoSuggestion(IntPtr handle, bool enable)
    {
        SHSetInputContext(handle, SHIC_FEATURE.AUTOSUGGEST, ref enable);
    }
}
```

You can then define what controls you want to control the functionality with by passing the handle:

```
InputContext.SetAutoSuggestion(txtBxInput.Handle, false);
```